# Как правильно передать данные в адресную строку в js?

Tags: javascript

данный скрипт читает данные с адресной строки `&state=[0,1]` и открывает либо прячет выпадающее меню, как мне правильно передать данные в адресную строку `(&state=[0,1])`?
`0 - hide`;
`1 - show`; в моем коде

```
<script>
var categoryList = $(".leftSideBarSubcategoryList");
    var state = '<?php echo json_encode($state); ?>';
    var state = JSON.parse(state);

    var dropElement = state.substring(1, state.length-1).split(',');

    var countCategoryList = categoryList.length;

    for (i=0; i<countCategoryList && i<dropElement.length; i++) {

        if (dropElement[i] == 1) {
                $(categoryList[i]).show();
            } else {
                $(categoryList[i]).hide();
            }
    };


    $("#box h3").click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        var text = $("span",this).text();
        $("span",this).text(text != "^" ? "^" : "v");
    });
    $(".leftSideBarElement").click(function(){
        $("li").removeClass("leftSideBarSelectedElement");
        $(this).addClass("leftSideBarSelectedElement");            
    });
});
</script>
<div id="box">
    <h3>Длина:<span class="expand">+</span></h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="..."></a>1 метр</li>
      <li><a href="..."></a>2 метра</li>
      <li><a href="..."></a>3 метра</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <h3>Ширина:<span class="expand">+</span></h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="..."></a>1 метр</li>
      <li><a href="..."></a>2 метра</li>
      <li><a href="..."></a>3 метра</li>                                       
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: если убрать кавычки тут: `var state = '<?php echo json_encode($state); ?>';` то следующая строка не нужна

Comment: в какой момент ты хочешь передавать значение в адресную строку?

Comment: @AGS17 в сниппет лучше переносить только рабочий код, а не тот, в котором используются конструкции php

Comment: Grundy, это 2 подменю которые открываются и закрываются.Я открыл первое - передался параметр в адресную строку и стало &state=[1,0], открыл второе - стало &state=[1,1] (по дефолту [0,0]), а при выборе пункта меню осуществляется переход и скрипт читает с адресной строки параметры и открывает менюхи согласно данным

Comment: Сначала была tak, теперь вообще "дропдаун"? Почему не выпадающее?

Comment: ну всмысле, что оно работает как дропдаун. ul список скрывается или открывается при нажатии